# Want to show a number into star rating in angular 5

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4

I am using angular 5.I want to show my rating number into star rating. How can i do this? I saw alot of tutorials for star rating, but they only worked when a user gave them rating. I just only want my number to show as star rating of a user. Here what i am doing.

app.component.html

```
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { AngularFirestore, AngularFirestoreCollection } from 
'angularfire2/firestore';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Component({
templateUrl: 'app.component.html'
}) 
export class AppComponent implements OnInit  {
users: Observable<any[]>;


constructor(private afs: AngularFirestore) {


this.users = this.afs.collection('users').valueChanges();
}

ngOnInit() {


}


  }
```

app.component.html

```
<div class="card-body">
      <table class="table">
        <thead>
          <tr>


            <th>Photo</th>
           <th>Name</th>
           <th>Email</th>
           <th>Rating</th>

              <th >delete</th>

          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr *ngFor="let user of users | async">

            <td >
              {{user.photoUrl}}
            </td>
    <td>
                     {{user.userName}}

                   </td>
                   <td >
                     {{user.email}}
                   </td>
                   <td>

                   {{user.rating}}// Want this user rating as number into star rating
                 </td>

                   <td>

                   {{user.id}}
                 </td>


                   <td>
                       <button class="btn btn-sm btn-danger"  
      (click)="onDelete(user.id)">delete</button>
                   </td>


  </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
   </div>
```

I want to show user.rating into star rating.Any help will be appreciated. Thankyou

Comment: If user.rating is a number use ngFor and print a start image in it

Comment: user.rating is a float number. Can u please give me  an example ? i want to show half star as well

Answer (score 2):

[This link will help you](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-starrating)

ng-starring is the way you need to do it, this link leads you to the site of npm.
Install it using npm install ng-starrating.
and then import it, `import { RatingModule } from 'ng-starrating';`
do not forget to add it to the import.

```
imports: [ BrowserModule, RatingModule ],
```

last you need to put this.

```
  <star-rating value="5" checkedcolor="red" uncheckedcolor="black" size="24px"    readonly="false" (rate)="onRate($event)"></star-rating>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use angular-star-rating for this.
First install angular-star-rating
 npm install angular-star-rating --save

then add it to your app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';  


// IMPORT YOUR LIBRARY
import { StarRatingModule } from 'angular-star-rating';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,

    // SPECIFY YOUR LIBRARY AS AN  IMPORT
    StarRatingModule.forRoot()
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

in your app.component.ts
instead of just {{user.rating}}
you can use this

```
<star-rating-comp [starType]="'svg'" [rating]="user.rating"></star-rating-comp>
```

Else you can create your own simple star rating as follows

```
<span *ngFor="let rat for user.rating" class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
```

CSS-

```
.checked {
    color: orange;
}
```

Comment: error occur when i used **<span *ngFor="let rat for user.rating" class="fa fa-star checked"></span>** as **Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'ngForFor' since it isn't a known property of 'span'.**

Comment: i used div instead of span and it works but user.rating is of float value ngFor its not working for that. e.g user.rating value is 4.33. How can i show this value in stars?

Answer (score 0):

Primeng RatingModule may help:-

Setup Link- https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/setup

```
1) npm install primeng --save
2) npm install primeicons --save
```

https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/rating

## module.ts

```
import {RatingModule} from 'primeng/rating';

imports: [
       RatingModule
    ]
```

## .html

```
<p-rating [(ngModel)]="val1"></p-rating>
```

Answer (score 0):

star-rating.html

```
    <div [formGroup]="parentFormGroup">
        <fieldset class="rating">
            <input type="radio" id="star5" [formControlName]="controlName" [value]="5" /><label class="full" for="star5"
                title="Excellent"></label>
            <input type="radio" id="star4half" [formControlName]="controlName" [value]="4.5" /><label class="half"
                for="star4half" title="Excellent"></label>
            <input type="radio" id="star4" [formControlName]="controlName" [value]="4" /><label class="full" for="star4"
                title="Good"></label>
            <input type="radio" id="star3half" [formControlName]="controlName" [value]="3.5" /><label class="half"
                for="star3half" title="Good"></label>
            <input type="radio" id="star3" [formControlName]="controlName" [value]="3" /><label class="full" for="star3"
                title="Average"></label>
            <input type="radio" id="star2half" [formControlName]="controlName" [value]="2.5" /><label class="half"
                for="star2half" title="Average"></label>
            <input type="radio" id="star2" [formControlName]="controlName" [value]="2" /><label class="full" for="star2"
                title="Fair"></label>
            <input type="radio" id="star1half" [formControlName]="controlName" [value]="1.5" /><label class="half"
                for="star1half" title="Fair"></label>
            <input type="radio" id="star1" [formControlName]="controlName" [value]="1" /><label class="full" for="star1"
                title="Poor"></label>
            <input type="radio" id="starhalf" [formControlName]="controlName" [value]="0.5" /><label class="half"
                for="starhalf" title="Poor"></label>
        </fieldset>
    </div>
```

star-rating.ts

```
    import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import { FormControl, FormControlName, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';

    @Component({
    selector: 'ma-star-ratings',
    templateUrl: './star-ratings.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./star-ratings.component.css']
    })
    export class StarRatingsComponent implements OnInit {

    @Input() controlName: any;
    @Input() parentFormGroup: FormGroup;
    constructor() { }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        // this.parentFormGroup.patchValue({
        //   [this.controlName] : 4
        // })
    }

    }
```

style.scss

```
    .rating {
    border: none;
    float: left;
    }

    .rating>input {
    display: none;
    }

    .rating>label:before {
    margin: 0.5rem;
    font-size: 1.25em;
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    display: inline-block;
    content: "\f005";
    }

    .rating>.half:before {
    content: "\f089";
    position: absolute;
    }

    .rating>label {
    color: #ddd;
    float: right;
    font-size: 1.4rem;
    }


    .rating {
        >input {
            &:checked~label {
            color: $orange !important;

            &:hover {
                color: $orange !important;
            }
            }

            &:not(:checked)~label {
            &:hover {
                color: $orange !important;

                ~label {
                color: $orange !important;
                }
            }
            }
        }

        >label {
            font-size: 2.8rem;
            cursor: pointer;
        }
        }
```